# Map View on Tab Bar project

Tags: xcode

I've got a tab-bar project in Xcode 4 and I'm trying to implement a map view on one of the tabs.

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrePrrHgXYA but I'm getting an error: Program received signal: "SIGBART" whenever I click the tab.

How come? Is it because the tutorial is only for view based projects? And if so, how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Error SIGBART can be shown when you don't import a Framework (like mapkit), o you try to use an object that has been released. Is a common error occurred when you badly connect (in IB o in code) with link pages or objects. You surely have done a big error in the code that prevent your app to run! Try to redo the last steps before the app stopped!